# Display different div jquery/css

Tags: jquery, css

I'd like to display 2 links that toggle the paragraph beneath them.

One link for first person, and the other for third person.

I have created a fiddle using some jQuery:

```
$("a#first").click(function(){
    $("div.thirdperson").fadeOut("");
    $("div.firstperson").fadeIn("");        
});
```

It works, but it's not as smooth as I'd like it to be. You can see the shifting.

I want to keep the text separated into two divs, and don't want to simply edit the text portion of the div using the ".text" jQuery command. eg:

```
$(this).text("DON'T PUSH ME");
```

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8k27p/

Comment: Ok using some absolute positioning?

Comment: Can you clarify if you want the shift to occur? Do you not want any shift or do you want the shift but you don't want the user to be able to see it. There's a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use callbacks... here is the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ERP7L/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("a#first").click(function(){
      $("div.thirdperson").fadeOut("",function(){
          $("div.firstperson").fadeIn(""); 
      });         
   });

   $("a#third").click(function(){  
      $("div.firstperson").fadeOut("",function(){
          $("div.thirdperson").fadeIn(""); 
      });        
   });
});
```

Comment: This answer seems to be the most secure, and doesn't require adding extra div wrappers. I like the subtle fade to white in between as well. Thanks!

Comment: all animations should be done using callback only if you want to perform some task because `delay()` does not accept a callback

Answer (score 1):

How about using .delay() in between the selector and the fadeIn(). Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nathanfrancy/8k27p/2/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a#first").click(function(){
        $("div.thirdperson").fadeOut("");
        $("div.firstperson").delay(500).fadeIn("");        
      });
    $("a#third").click(function(){
        $("div.firstperson").fadeOut(""); 
        $("div.thirdperson").delay(500).fadeIn("");       
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/8k27p/1/

Use a single selector and toggle the visibility.

```
$('.person').toggle();
```

Comment: I believe he was looking for the `fade` effect.

Comment: That's not how I understand *You can see the shifting* which seems to be the issue here.

Comment: Touche. I suppose we'll wait for a response from OP.

Answer (score 0):

## Will this work for you?

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/8k27p/5/

I basically just made a `wrapper` (position:relative) so it will actually follow the `structure` of the `DOM`, then `position:absolute` the `div`s inside of them so they float over one another.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="firstperson">
        <strong>First Person.</strong> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.
    </div>

    <div class="thirdperson">
        <strong>Third Person.</strong> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.nav{
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

.thirdperson{
    display:none;
}
.wrapper {
    position:relative;
}
.thirdperson, .firstperson{
    position:absolute;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("a#first").click(function(){
        $("div.thirdperson").fadeOut("");
        $("div.firstperson").fadeIn("");        
      });

    $("a#third").click(function(){
        $("div.firstperson").fadeOut(""); 
        $("div.thirdperson").fadeIn("");       
      });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another possible solution for your issue. First wrap your `firstperson` and `thirdperson` in a container with the class `copy`, and then try out this js:

**[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/badAdviceGuy/8k27p/7/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.nav').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
       e.preventDefault()

       var target = $(this).index(); 
        $('.copy div').hide();
        $('.copy').children().eq(target).fadeIn('fast');
    });
});
```